# Use Tonelli's theorem to show an inequality resulting from the convolution of integrable functions.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f$ and $g$ be Lebesgue integrable functions on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ to $\mathbb R$. If $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B$, use Tonelli's theorem and the fact that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x-y)|\ \mathsf d\lambda(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|\ \mathsf d\lambda(x)
$$
to show that the function $h$ defined for $x\in\mathbb R$ by
$$
h(x) = \int_{\mathbb R}f(x-y)g(y)\ \mathsf d\lambda(y)
$$
is finite almost everywhere. Moreover,
$$
\int |h|\ \mathsf d\lambda \leqslant \left[\int |f|\ \mathsf d\lambda\right]\left[\int |g|\ \mathsf d\lambda\right].
$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: A fellow teacher gave me the following tip, but I don't know how to follow it:

1.Prove the statement for functions of the form 1A where A is an interval.

2.Then you have it for every step function by linearity of the integral.

3.Then use the fact that step functions are dense in the class of Lebesgue integrable functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: define $F(x,y) := |f(x-y)g(y)|$ which is measurable and nonnegative. Apply Tonelli's Theorem to $F$ and see what you get for the first part. For the second part, recall that:
$$\bigg{|}\int f d\mu \bigg{|} \le \int |f|d\mu.$$